# docker multi-stage - why copy part of a folder resulting in bigger image than copy the entire folder?

Tags: docker

I want to create the smallest image possible for my project, so I am using multi-stage docker with distroless. I copy only the files that needed for runtime. From several folders I copy only the `.so` files instead of copy all the folder and I can see that the created image get smaller.

But there is one folder that when I copy the entire folder I get smaller image significally than copy only the `.so` files.

With the following Dockerfile I copy the entire /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder:

```
#stage 1
FROM some_image AS builder

ADD something /home/

RUN mkdir ...
    cmake ...

#stage 2
FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian10

COPY --from=builder /home/some/folders
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

WORKDIR /home/

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

And the image size is 618MB.

But with the following Dockerfile I copy only the `*.so` files from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder:

```
#stage 1
FROM some_image AS builder

ADD something /home/

RUN mkdir ...
    cmake ...

#stage 2
FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian10

COPY --from=builder /home/some/folders
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*.so.* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

WORKDIR /home/

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

And surprisingly the image size is now 683MB. Which is 65MB bigger.

Any idea what can cause such results?

Comment: Have you examined the resulting image when you copy the folder only, so see what is actually in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` ?

Comment: This is based on a distroless imgae so there is no shell. But I examine it with the Dive tool and I can see that in one image the files in x86_64-linux-gnu are only *.so file while in the other image there are also other types. The size of the x86_64-linux-gnu folder with only *.so files is 438MB while in the other image is 366MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long investigation I found that:

- **Copy of entire folder with symlinks preserves symlinks**
- **Copy symlinks directly creates regular files**

So in my case, copy of all `*.so` files cause each symlink to be copied as a regular file that this symlink is pointing on. This transition cause the increasing of my image size.

After I understand that, I google it and found a reference [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/1111#issuecomment-596015015)